# Showing that the map $\phi_e(x) = |x|^e, e \geq 1$ is $\mathcal{O}(h)$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm not entirely sure how one shows that the map $\phi_e(x) = |x|^e, e \geq 1$ is $\mathcal{O}(h)$, i.e. that for some $c > 0: \left|\phi_e(h)\right| \leq c|h|$ for all *small enough* $h$. Namely either the proof is super-simple, or I'm missing something entirely. My current reasoning is that if $e = 1$, then by choosing any $c \geq 1$ we are done. And when $e > 1$, setting $c = 1$ finishes the proof as when $|h| < 1$, $|h|^e < |h|$.

Comment: looks fine to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy indeed. Take for example $c=1$. Then
$$
K(h):= \frac{\lvert \varphi_e(h) \rvert}{\lvert h \rvert} = \lvert h \rvert^{e-1}
$$
Note that we have to find a bound for $K(h)$ if $h$ is very small. If $e=1$, then $\lvert \varphi_e(h) \rvert =\lvert h \rvert$, so we are good. If $e>1$, then we even have $K(h) = \lvert h \rvert^{e-1} \rightarrow 0$ as $h \rightarrow 0$. Therefore $K(h)$ gets arbitrarily small and we can choose any $c > 0$. Your reasoning is aboslutely correct.